# Calculating the DC motor fraction coefficient

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller

So I have been designing a DC motor controller and I ran into a problem rather complicated. So for modeling the mechanical block we require motor inertia as well as friction coefficient. But my problem is that there are two different friction coefficient alike in two different equations:

1. The general equation for for all rotating machines:
   [image]
2. Coefficient of friction based on inertia and motor mechanical time constant which is B=J/Taum

Now based on some calculation on the motor (its a robot. so Im guessing the motors are loaded but can figure out the load torque) this equations has been provided for me:
[image]

which is in similar form as the first equation. Based on this equation the value of B is supposed to be 4.3e-5. While if I calculate it based on the 2nd equation it corresponds to 9.67e-5 (based on the motor datasheet J=5.8e-7 and Taum=6ms).

the thing is that Im not sure which value should be used in the mechanical block in my Simulink design. Should I calculate B by substituting Tem and rated speed in the first equation, Or substituting J and Taum in the 2nd equation, Or assume B is equal to 4.3e-5 based on the equation provided in the design requirement?
(the last equation is based on practical measurement that was conducted on the robot to calculate the rolling friction, the bearing friction and the aerodynamics drag)